# GET Shift Preference Issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Having an error when getting this API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shiftpreferences-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Request header:

```
{'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ**6MA', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'MS-APP-ACTS-AS': '53**76'}
```

Error Response: `{'error': {'code': 'Forbidden', 'message': '{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"The user identifier in the path does not match the one in the authorization token.","details":[],"innererror":{"code":"InvalidOAuthToken"}}}', 'innerError': {'date': '2020-10-06T13:53:08', 'request-id': '093**ad', 'client-request-id': '09**bad'}}}`

And I have all permissions required for this.

Any Idea why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can easily reproduce your problem.

[image]

This error will occur if you use the wrong user_id or the token you use is not issued by the user. You can use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and view **oid** Claims, which is your user_id and also Token issuer, you need to ensure that it is consistent with the user_id in your request path.

[image]

[image]

There is also a relatively simple method, you can directly use [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to request this API (this requires you to log in).

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks this answer the question. What I did to fix it is the header "MS-APP-ACTS-AS" I added the same user UID as the user i am searching for.